# Visualizing the detection process in Mask-RCNN

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

I am working on a project that aims to detect objects in certain difficult circumstances. I ran a test with *Mask_RCNN* on a dataset that contains that specific type of difficult examples and it did a pretty good job in some of them.

But some other examples didn't get detected surprisingly, when there is no obvious reason. To understand the reason behind this performance difference, I've been adviced to use **Tensorboard**. But then I realized that its mostly used for training phase, as I understood from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4).

At the end of the video, however, they mention about an integration project of **Tensorboard**, namely the **Tensorflow Debugger Integration**. But unfortunately I could not find further information regarding the continuation about that feature.

Is there any way to visualize weights and activation maps inside a **CNN** during inference/evaluation phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between training and inference time for tensorboard will be the global_step value. Most graphs display `global step` as the x-axis. You can supply your own global step counter if you like, but you'll have to decide what the x-axis should represent to you in this case since "time" isn't really a logical construct during inference. Other tabs such as the images tab don't have a time component, so using them should be the same as during training.

The tensorflow debugger is a nice terminal debugger, but wouldn't really be related to what you're trying to do here. It's certainly not a visualization tool.

Another approach might be to simply generate your own plots and output a set of PDFs with the various visualizations you need using standard tools like matplotlib for each test image. I've found tools like XnView make it really easy to look through a lot of PDF visualizations to understand what's going on. I've used this approach quite effectively. If you want to view many hundreds or thousands of results quickly you might have an easier time if all the visuals are just dumped out to a directory.